# Will PropertyVersionBase be removed, or replaced by more specific base classes?

Tags: ocean

PropertyVersionBase has been marked obsolete for a long while.
Currently, it's the only way to maintain a reference to either Template or DictionaryTemplate, or to either WellLogVersion or DictionaryWellLogVersion, etc.

The confusion with PropertyVersion[Base] is that it was also the base class for e.g. *WellLogVersion, which are fundamentally different from Template classes - a controversial design decision (IMHO) early on in Ocean.

I would appreciate some clarification:

Will this base class eventually be removed?

Will there be a base class for Template and DictionaryTemplate?

Will there be a base class for WellLogVersion and DictionaryWellLogVersion?

In general, where is these class hierarchies going in the future?

(I'd like to tag on a second question: could any base class also expose Droid, pretty please?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PropertyVersionBase was marked obsolete in 2012.1, but DictionaryPropertyVersion was missed (it was only deprecated in 2012.2). So due to the Ocean stability promise we will keep both in 2013.1 and remove them in 2014.1.
There was no plan for base classes so far (Object is the common replacement base). But we may  consider to add specific base classes for 2014.1. This would simplify some of our APIs too where the attached template can be dictionary or continuous template.
Thanks for the suggestion.
Best Regards,
Gaelle